# AWS process large batch of small files daily

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have intermediate AWS knowledge and have an issue, where I can see multiple ways of solving it, and I'm looking for opinions from more skilled AWS architects.

I have an on-premise system that produces ~30k XML files (each <100KB) throughout the day. These XML files have to be sent to AWS to be parsed.

Possible solutions:

1. Feed the XML files to a Kinesis Firehose (presumably via an API gateway) that parses each file in a lambda and also stores the raw files in S3. This is, in my opinion, the ideal solution (?). A new XML file is created approx. every 3 seconds.
2. Upload each XML file via a presigned S3 URL and trigger a lambda that parses it. This involves fetching a presigned URL for every file from an API gateway. I am unsure whether this is a good approach for files that are produced at the above mentioned frequency.
3. Same as above, but use SFTP for the upload.

Out of these 3 solutions, I think **option 1** is most suitable, but I'm eager to hear opinions on this.

There is also a scenario, where the XML files are collected every day into a batch of ~30k files. For that case, I have the following questions:

- Does **option 1** still make sense, even though the firehose is fed only once a day with a large amount of files at once?
- Does **option 2/3** still make sense? Another possibility would be to upload a single zip, unzip it with a lambda into another folder, where again, a lambda is triggered for every new files. That would mean 30k lambdas being triggered at once.
- There are S3 batch operation, that apply a lambda to every file in a predetermined list of files. Where is the difference to the zip-version of **option 2**? It also seems that these s3 batch operations cannot be provisioned with terraform, which is a disadvantage for me.

I understand that this question is not super specific, but I would appreciate help.

One concrete question that I have is: does triggering 30k lambdas "at once" pose an issue? The tasks are not time-sensitive, so it's not a problem that "only" 1k lambdas are running in parallell, as long as all of them eventually run.

Comment: Note that the default maximum quota for Lambda function concurrent executions is 1,000, but this can be raised.

Comment: @jarmod I'm aware, but is it correct that if the processing speed is not important, triggering 30k lambdas at once is not an issue, because while the concurrency limit will be hit, the lambdas will retry again? So eventually, all of them should complete at some point?

Comment: Decouple the arrival of the XML files from the downstream consumer (your Lambda function). Arrival of XML files sends an [S3 event to SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html). Configure a Lambda function to process a batch of messages from SQS, for example 10 at a time if that fits, or 1 at aa time if they need to be done independently. Set the [max Lambda concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/) as you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, sounds great, didn't think of SQS. How would you compare this approach to the distributed map approach discussed in one of the answers? Ultimately, they seem very similar.

Comment: The SF distributed map option works well if all the map inputs are known at a given time and it's well-suited to operations over S3 objects. It provides better visibility into the workflow. The SQS approach can immediately start processing batches as they arrive so you don't need to wait. Also see the "When should I use Step Functions vs. Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)?" [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/faqs/)

Comment: Thanks again. It sounds like the SF approach is best suited for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheapest solution so far would be using the [distributed map](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/step-functions-distributed-map-a-serverless-solution-for-large-scale-parallel-data-processing/) feature of AWS Step Functions.

Regarding your file upload you need to decide how fast you need your data be accessible after being processed. Hence uploading all in one batch or when they occur is bound to that.

Independently of your upload interval I would use the event from S3 that a new file has arrived, batch them and process them with Step Functions. To reduce costs, use an Express Workflow.

There are a couple of file integrations from on premise to cloud. You can write a script that puts files into S3 directly, upload them via API Gateway or use more sophisticated services like AWS DataSync or AWS Storage Gateway. Depending on how stable your connection is, you could directly mount S3 into your filesystem like described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/mountpoint-for-amazon-s3-generally-available-and-ready-for-production-workloads/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and thanks for editing @jarmod). This sounds like a really good fit for my problem.
My approach would be to upload the zipped XML files to S3, which will trigger a lambda to unzip it and do some bucket preparations. The lambda will then start the step function. The step function workflow might have to be standard, not sure if 5 minutes will suffice, but the child workflows can definitely be express. And the concurrency will have to be limited to 1,000, since my lambda limit is standard. Feel free to comment on this approach.

Comment: I still have one question though: Does this fundamentally differ from unzipping into S3 and having a lambda triggered by new objects? Unzipping would immediately launch 1,000 concurrent lambdas, with all others failing due to the rate limit, but retrying until eventually succeeding. I understand that step functions are much cleaner in this regard, but is it really different, or even cheaper?
Maybe you can comment on this too @jarmod, because it ties into your comment on my question.

Comment: Well the difference is that with Step Function you have more control. The amount of files might change and with the Map function you can cover all those cases. Ultimately other lambdas in your account might get throttled when S3 triggers a lot of events. Your approach with compromising rate limiting seems dangerous to me

Comment: If the answer fits you might mark it as answer. That would be great @WolfSovereign

Comment: I definitely will, but I want to test it first and report back if any issues arise. Please give me a few more days.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to process the files and each file processing time and whether you want real time processsing or batch style.

**firehose + lambda:**

Though the firehose + lambda option is more convenient to setup, frequent execution of lambda ( every 3 seconds) will have higher cost involved. Same case will be for kinesis firehose, that it charges based on amount of data processed. So if you are up for it, I would say do a cost analysis on your case.

**Alternative approach:**

If you have your files every 3 seconds created and have condition of real-time processing, a long running microservice is recommended to read the file from s3 and process/parse it and do the further processing.

If you are okay with processing the files once per day at certain desirable time, choosing an AWS ECS scheduled task with any batch framework like spring batch will be beneficial.  With that you can have AWS ECS scheduled task, running at specific time and processing your files reading it from s3. after the processing, the job shut down, so it wont incur any cost.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Real-time processing with firehose would be my desired approach, but for reasons that don't concern me, the produced files are collected into batches once per day. Having an ECS task seems almost overkill to me, the parsing is very simple, it's just a matter of extracting information from each XML and sending it into a DB.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned "batch", you should explore AWS Batch: https://aws.amazon.com/batch/

If you have not heard about AWS Batch, here is the description:

**What is AWS Batch?**

AWS Batch is a set of batch management capabilities that enables developers, scientists, and engineers to easily and efficiently run hundreds of thousands of batch computing jobs on AWS. AWS Batch dynamically provisions the optimal quantity and type of compute resources (e.g., CPU or memory optimized compute resources) based on the volume and specific resource requirements of the batch jobs submitted. With AWS Batch, there is no need to install and manage batch computing software or server clusters, allowing you to instead focus on analyzing results and solving problems. AWS Batch plans, schedules, and executes your batch computing workloads using Amazon ECS, Amazon EKS, and AWS Fargate with an option to utilize spot instances.

---

To utilize AWS Batch, you create a container that contain whatever code and business logic that you want it to execute, and you execute it against a target storage, like S3.

The good thing about AWS Batch is you can use Spot Instance which will save you money, and if that instance was interrupted and the task did not complete, AWS Batch will reschedule another replacement instance to redo the task.

It does not matter if you want to process 1 file or 1 million file in your S3 bucket.

And to transfer your local file to S3 bucket, you can use AWS Storage Gateway to sync/upload your local file to S3, and trigger the AWS Batch process: https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I will look into it. I must say that the distributed map approach with AWS step functions, mentioned in another answer, seems like a better fit. Feel free to give your opinion on that.